# Case:If the user selected "Dont allow" on app install for Photo,sound,badges permissions. How can i ask the user to Allow?

Tags: ios, notifications, push

Case:If the user selected "Dont allow" on app install for Photo,sound,badges permissions. How can i ask the user to Allow??

Comment: when user clicks Not Allow is there any alternative for IOS permissions?

Answer (score 1):

So basically you can't ask a second time.
Some apps do that way:

They present an alert explaining why they need that permission, then if the user press "allow" they show the popup from Apple. If the user answer no to that one, you are basically screw :/

You can always explain the user how to allow the access by going into the Settings app of the iPhone.

Here is a nice article about that issue:
https://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/

And why it's a very critical step for your app:

> Making it all worse is that when a user taps “Don’t Allow”, there is
>   no easy way for them to reverse that decision. It takes five steps to
>   grant access later, and there’s no way to help a user navigate to the
>   right screen besides actually listing the steps.

Comment: when user clicks "Not Allow" can show alert to enable permissions in settings later?

Comment: So you **cannot** show the permission pop up in your app a second time, but **the user can** go in the general settings and enable the permissions. But this process is long, and most users never do it. So basically if the user denied the access the first time, you will most certainly never got it.